# Matplotlib imread() color setting parameters suggesstion

Tags: matplotlib

This is a very weird question. I am using `plt.imshow()` to read spectrograms and I need to make a graph like this color style. The background is blue-ish.

[image]

But now I'm getting this

[image]

Can anyone recommend some parameters?

Comment: The example seems to be the `jet` colormap, which is [highly discouraged](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2014/10/16/how-bad-is-your-colormap/) for this kind for visualizations. For standard matplotlib, the ['Perceptually Uniform Sequential'](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html) such as 'viridis', 'plasma', 'inferno', 'magma', 'cividis' are encouraged. 'Viridis' is the default, and what you got. Probably plasma is close to your needs.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice. I tried the map you recommended and switched the original to 'plasma'.

Answer (score -1):

Just add this line `plt.style.use("classic")`.

Comment: No, please don't ever do this.